# member function referring to an object's member function

Tags: c++, constructor, member-functions

I'm a c++ noob so apologies in advance if this question is not properly structured.

I have a class which instantiates an object of a different class, I'd like for the member function of the main class (excuse my naive language) to be in turn referring to the member function of the object instantiated in the main class.

I've attached a snippet for reference

**foo.h**

```
class foo {
public : 

int data;
void printFunc(){
cout<< "data is"<< data;
}

};
```

**bar.h**

```
class bar {

public:
void updatebarr ();
}
```

**bar.cpp**

```
bar::bar()
{
foo foo1;
foo1.data = 1; 
// the line below is flagged as syntax error
// I want the object of type bar's updatebarr() function to be essentially be calling 
// foo::PrintFunc(). I figured this "should" work as the signatures are identical.
this->updatebarr = &foo1.printFunc(); 
}
```

The error I get is "Reference to non-static member function must be called",

Comment: If you want " object of type bar's `updatebarr()` function to be essentially be calling `foo::PrintFunc`" then put a call to PrintFunc inside `updatebarr()`, that's it. You don't accomplish this by setting `updatebarr` like it's some kind of a pointer. C++ does not work this way. There are no shortcuts to learning C++ except via a guided, organized approach presented by a well-written C++ textbook. The chances of randomly guessing the correct C++ syntax for doing something are absolutely nil, if not negative. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today.

Comment: Well, if you are new to C++, I would not recommend you to do that. Member function pointer are rarely used in C++. Usually, one might start by using an OOP approach with virtual function to call. And if generic callback are need, one should consider using `std::function` with a lambda which is somewhat advanced C++. Having said that, given that `foo1` is a local variable in your constructor, the callback would have undefined behavior and probably crash if you call `updatebarr` after the object is constructed… so it make little sense to have a member of that type.

Answer (score 1):

The signatures might look similar but these are not free functions but [member functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members). Have a look at this faq!

The type of the first one is: `void (foo::*)()` and the second is `void (bar::*)()`. See the difference?

They can only be invoked on an object of their respective type. What you can do is this:

```
class bar {
  public:
    void updatebarr(foo& f) {
      f.printFunc();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointers to member methods do not work the way you are trying.  Not only what you have is a syntax error, but it is also a logic error since `foo1` will go out of scope and be destroyed when `bar()` exits, thus leaving `updatebarr` to call `printFunc()` on an invalid `foo` object.

For what you are attempting, you would need something more like this:

foo.h

```cpp
class foo {
public : 
    int data;
    void printFunc(){
        cout << "data is " << data;
    }
};
```

bar.h

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

class bar {
private:
    foo foo1;
public:
    bar();
    void updatebarr();
};
```

bar.cpp

```cpp
#include "bar.h"

bar::bar()
{
    foo1.data = 1; 
}

void bar::updatebarr()
{
    foo1.printFunc();
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    bar b;
    b.updatebarr();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/rYzjuG)

Alternatively, you can make `updatebarr()` be a `std::function` that calls `printFunc()` via a lambda, eg:

foo.h

```cpp
class foo {
public : 
    int data;
    void printFunc(){
      cout << "data is " << data;
    }
};
```

bar.h

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include "foo.h"

class bar {
private:
    foo foo1;
public:
    bar();
    std::function<void()> updatebarr;
};
```

bar.cpp

```cpp
#include "bar.h"

bar::bar()
{
    foo1.data = 1; 
    updatebarr = [&](){ foo1.printFunc(); };
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    bar b;
    b.updatebarr();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/pFm6vN)

In which case, you could then have the lambda capture *a copy* of the `foo` object instead, which will give you a result very close to your original attempt, eg:

foo.h

```cpp
class foo {
public : 
    int data;
    void printFunc() const {
      cout << "data is " << data;
    }
};
```

bar.h

```cpp
#include <functional>

class bar {
public:
    bar();
    std::function<void()> updatebarr;
};
```

bar.cpp

```cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"

bar::bar()
{
    foo foo1;
    foo1.data = 1; 
    updatebarr = [foo1](){ foo1.printFunc(); };
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    bar b;
    b.updatebarr();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/UiNqTi)